# content on all 4 sides of my Sony TV are cut off when connected via HDMI to be a second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-manager

I have connected a sony TV to my laptop through HDMI port to use as a second monitor. But, content is being cut off on all four sides are cut off like shown in images below:
top-left:
[image]
bottom-left
[image]

Here's the output of xrandr in terminal:

```
naveen@naveen-hp:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/344x1080/193+1920+0  eDP-1
 1: +HDMI-1 1920/1600x1080/900+0+0  HDMI-1
```

My laptop's display and my TV, both are 1920x1080 60HZ displays.

Here's information about it in my settings page:
[image]

I couldn't find anything even similar to overscan or underscan in my TV settings, the settings are very basic in the TV. when I connect to the very same TV from windows 10, I don't see content on all 4 sides being chopped off like this. So, I presume this got to be something with Ubuntu. How do I fix this.

More info about my laptop: Intel core i5-8250U, no NVidia or any dedicated graphics card, but Intel Integrated graphics and on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I had to change a setting on my TV when this happened.  On my KC tv it was in the Picture/Advanced Settings menu, I set the HDMI Mode  to Graphic.

Comment: I have had this problem it is a setting on the tv it is the overscan setting i changed mine to just scan but what it is called depends on the tv here is a link with some info https://www.cnet.com/news/overscan-youre-not-seeing-the-whole-picture-on-your-tv/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me @OrganicMarble, in settings>Picture> I only have standard/vivid/custom to change how to colors are displayed. As i had said, my TV has very very basic settings and I didn't have to tweak anything when I used to do this with windows 10.

Comment: On my Sony TV, I had to set Settings -> Screen -> Display Area to "Full Pixel"

Comment: I believe this is a hardware issue (TV overscan), that has nothing to do with Ubuntu.